# How to create wechatUrl source using Stripe ios SDK?

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, wechat

I followed this [document](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/wechat-pay) and create source successfully, but couldn't find out how to get wechat_url variable. My create source function:

```
func createWechatSource(withAmount amount: NSNumber, completion: @escaping STPSourceCompletionBlock) {
    var currency = "HKD"
    var returnUrl = "appname://stripe-redirect"
    let sourceParam = STPSourceParams()
    sourceParam.type = .unknown
    sourceParam.rawTypeString = "wechat"
    sourceParam.currency = currency
    sourceParam.amount = amount
    sourceParam.owner?.updateValue("example", forKey: "name")
    sourceParam.owner?.updateValue(returnUrl, forKey: "returnURL")
    STPAPIClient.shared().createSource(with: sourceParam, completion: completion)
}
```

I don't know if there's a lot of people people in here who are familiar with Stripe/ Wechat Pay, but I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: get help by Stripe supporter, I find out how to get the wechat.URL. Source stores it at allFieldResponse dictionary property.